# Using scipy.optimize's curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

----ANSWERED----

I apologize if this question is too simply answered. I'm very new to Python coding and am currently taking on a difficult project. Any help is appreciated; I'd be happy to clarify confusion for those willing to assist.

I was able to successfully fit my data with this function, but the binding model was inaccurate (thermodynamic values resulting were incorrect):

```
#defining function of the binding model 
def binding_model(molar_ratio,Ka,n,dH):
    return (dH*molar_ratio**n)/(molar_ratio**n+Ka**n)

#fitting molar enthalpy vs. molar ratio data with binding model
initial_paramaters=array([1,0,0])   
parameters,cov=curve_fit(binding_model,molar_ratio,peak_areas,initial_paramaters)
n=parameters[0]
Ka=parameters[1]
dH=parameters[2]
Ffit=binding_model(molar_ratio,n,Ka,dH)
```

I corrected the binding model (to a single-site ligand binding model), but I cannot get the curve_fit function to work anymore:

```
#defining function of the binding model 
def binding_model(Mt,Xt,Vcell,Ka,n,dH):
    return (n*Mt*dH*Vcell/2)*(1+(Xt/(Mt*n))+(1/(n*Ka*Mt)))-((1+(Xt/(n*Mt))+(1/(n*Ka*Mt)))**2-(4*Xt/(Mt*n))**.5)
#fitting molar enthalpy vs. molar ratio data with binding model
initial_paramaters=array([1,0,0])   
parameters=curve_fit(binding_model,Mt,Xt,Vcell,peak_areas,initial_paramaters)
n=parameters[0]
Ka=parameters[1]
dH=parameters[2]
Ffit=binding_model(Mt,Xt,Ka,n,dH,Vcell)
```

It now returns a "curve_fit() takes at most 5 arguments (6 given)" error.

molar_ratio, Mt, and Xt are three arrays, each consist of 41 values. Vcell is an integer extracted from the data. Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: Do yourself a favour and split the formula. Use a few temporary variables, giving them relevant terms. A long formula as it is now is a bug magnet.

Comment: How do you mean? The only variables are Mt and Xt (both lists of an equal number of arrays) and Vcell (an integer). I don't know if I can make it any more simple. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Like this: `term1 = n*Mt*dH*Vcell/2; term2= 1+(Xt/(Mt*n); ... return term1 * term2 + ...` And even better if you can give `term1, term2...` significant names (like kinetic term...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just not using it properly;

read how it works [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

say i wanted to fit a polynomial to some data;

i could have something like this:

```
def quad(xdata, a,b,c):
    return a * xdata**2 + b * xdata + c
```

then i could have some data;

```
xdata = np.array([range(10)])
ydata = np.array([1 for _ in xdata])
```

and then i could call curve_fit;

```
initial_guess = [0,0,0]
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(quad, xdata, ydata, p0=initial_guess)

print popt # [0,0,1]
```

The issue you were having is that you weren't putting you initial guess into an array for the `p0` argument (which is optional anyway).

For your function, try this (i have not tested it, i don't have python on this machine):

```
def binding_model(xdata,Vcell,Ka,n,dH):
  Mt = xdata[0]
  Xt = xdata[1]
  return (n*Mt*dH*Vcell/2)*(1+(Xt/(Mt*n))+(1/(n*Ka*Mt)))-((1+(Xt/(n*Mt))+(1/(n*Ka*Mt)))**2-(4*Xt/(Mt*n))**.5)

#fitting molar enthalpy vs. molar ratio data with binding model

initial_Vcell = 0
initial_Ka = 0
initial_n = 0
initial_dH = 0

initial_paramaters=array([initial_Vcell, initial_Ka, initial_n, initial_dH])   
xdata = zip(Mt, Xt) 
parameters, cov = curve_fit(binding_model, xdata, ydata, p0=initial_paramaters)


Vcell=parameters[0]
Ka=parameters[1]
n=parameters[2]
dH=parameters[3]

Ffit=binding_model(xdata, Vcell, Ka, n, dH)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Are lines 5 and 6 in my code above not sufficient? It seems I've already done that in the form of 'initial_parameters.'

Comment: You've changed the number of parameters your binding_model function takes though. You need to add those to the `initial_parameters` array.

Comment: The `curve_fit` routine is essentially going to call your function like this: `binding_model(xdata, *initial_parameters)` and then compare the output to `ydata` You only really need to give it your function, xdata, and ydata.

Comment: Click on the link i provided, and reada how to use `curve_fit`. You give it the x values, and the corresponding y values. It will then optimise the rest of the function parameters such that the function produces `ydata` given `xdata`. I do not know if you can use arrays as some of the inputs though. You can hard code the arrays into the function though, then it will optimise the other variables. You do not need to use the `p0` initial guess keyword argument, unless you have problems with it converging to the wrong answer.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the help. I commented out my block of code and replaced it with yours. I received a strange error though. "parameters,cov=curve_fit(binding_model,xdata,p0=initial_paramaters)
TypeError: curve_fit() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)." It doesn't seem to make any sense to me.

Comment: Looks like you're missing `ydata`, you should call the fit like `curve_fit(binding_model, xdata, ydata, p0=initial_paramaters)` where `xdata` are your independent variable(s) and `ydata` is the dependent variable (data you are fitting to).

Comment: Whoops. Edited to fix.

Comment: Just had another look, and if assume that xdata needs to be a zipped up array of all the xdata you're passing in too, so added that.

Comment: I've applied your fixes to my program and just need to change my operand types. Thank you all for your time and help!

Comment: I've since dodged operand issues with '/' by changing xdata to a list of arrays but am now getting 'ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2) (41)'; I suspect the structure of 'xdata' you proposed (both arrays in xdata are 41 numbers long) is creating the issue. Is there any way you see correcting this? I apologize if my skill with debugging seems inadequate.

Comment: @MrPibbXIX Why do you need to do this? What are these "operand issues" ?

Comment: Using the code you wrote, I return: 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'tuple'' for my binding model (since broken up): `    def binding_model(xdata,Vcell,Ka,n,dH):    
    Mt=xdata[0]
    Xt=xdata[1]
    a=(n/2)*Mt*dH*Vcell
    b=1+Xt/(Mt*n)
    c=1/(n*Ka*Mt)
    d=1+(Xt/(n*Mt))+(1/(n*Ka*Mt))
    e=4*Xt/(Mt*n)
    return a*(b+c)-(d**2-e**.5)`

Comment: Ahh. try changing `Mt=xdata[0]` to `Mt=np.array(xdata[0])` and the same of `Xt`. The problem is they are no longer numpy arrays, which support the division stuff.

Comment: I tried. That returns 'ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2) (41)'

Comment: Did it ever work? And if it did, what have you changed?

Comment: No, I haven't been able to get it to produce any fit yet. I edited the question to add all the changes I've done so far. It's a lot easier to see in that format than in comment.